# How to integrate Next.js server-side rendering with a legacy PHP application?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a legacy PHP application and I'm trying to add server-side rendering using Next.js. I've followed the instructions on the Next.js documentation and created a pages directory for my Next.js application. However, I'm not sure how to go forward, the goal being that I inject next.js components or pages in different files of the php application.

Here's what I've done so far:

I've created a Next.js page at pages/Index.js that contains a simple component:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function HomePage() {
  useEffect = () => {
    console.log("Hello from Next.js");
  };
  return <div>Welcome to my Next.js homepage!</div>;
}
```

I've added the next dependency to my package.json file and added a script to watch for changes to my pages and components directories:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "next": "nodemon --watch pages --watch components --exec 'next build'"
  }
}
```

I've added a build configuration to my next.config.js file:

```
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require("webpack-manifest-plugin");
module.exports = {
  distDir: "/output",
  optimizeFonts: false,
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new WebpackManifestPlugin({
        fileName: "manifest.json",
        publicPath: "/output",
      })
    );
    if (!isServer) {
      config.devtool = "source-map";
    }
    config.optimization.minimize = false;
    return config;
  },
};
```

I've added a div element with the id of next_component to my PHP template:

```
<div id="next_component"></div>
```

In my parent PHP template, I've added a script tag that loads the latest build of my Next.js page:

```
<?php 
$manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(TL_ROOT . '/output/manifest.json'), true); 
$latestBuild = $manifest['pages/Index.js']; 
> 
<script src="<?php echo $latestBuild; ?>"></script><!-- //! NEXT JS HERE -->
```

Finally, I've added a script to my Next.js page that mounts the component to the next_component element:

```
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./Index";
const ComponentToRender = (Component, element, reduxStore) => {
  render(<Component {...element.dataset} />, element);
};
const element =
  typeof window !== "undefined" && document.getElementById("next_component");
if (element) {
  ComponentToRender(HomePage, element, false);
}
```

However, when I load my PHP page in the browser, the Next.js component doesn't seem to be rendering. What am I missing ?

Comment: I'm gonna guess that you haven't deployed your app using the build comman.

Comment: npm run next script will run the next build command which should deploy the next app.
the Network clearly show the Index.js file has been correctly downloaded. but at not point is this     console.log("Hello from Next.js"); executed on the client side for some reason.